# iOS 7: Background fetch starting time

Tags: ios7, time, background, fetch

I have a question regarding Background Fetch on iOS 7.

When does the timer of this background fetch start?

I.e: I start my app at 6:05pm and set my minimum background fetch interval to be 1 hour

```
[application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval: 3600];
```

Does this mean that my app will wake up at 7:05pm and perform the fetch? Or it will wake up at 7:00pm, 8:00pm, 9:00pm ... ?

The reason why I ask the question if because we want to schedule the fetch so that the load will be spreaded across 24 hour. Otherwise, there may be peak time when all the devices wake up and perform the fetch at the same time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Tests were conducted. Turned out, MinimumBackgroundFetchInterval give developers little control over when the background fetch kicks in.

I.e: Given MinimumBackgroundFetchInterval = 60, the app will NOT do background fetch more than one time within 60 seconds.

Apple have their own algorithm to work out when the app needs updating based on the app's usage